# find the Day of week of a particular date

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have an object which has 2 dates startdate_*c and enddate*_c .
i need to find a way to find the days of week these dates fall in

For example 
 startdate = 1 jun 2012 and enddate = 3 jun2012
I need to know which days of the week the days between these dates fall in.
In this example 
Mon = false, tue = false, wed = false, thu=false, fri=true,sat=true,sun=true

I want to use this in a Vf page to render the somefields based on the boolean value.

Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date has a method called `toStartOfWeek` which you could leverage, assuming your two dates do lie within the same week you could simply do something like this:

```
date weekStart = startdate.toStartOfWeek();
list<boolean> days = new list<boolean>();

for(integer i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  days.add(weekStart.addDays(i) >= startdate && weekStart.addDays(i) <= enddate);
}
```

A little bit crude, but it'll give you an array of 7 boolean values. For longer/unknown ranges you could use a date cursor and increment that instead of an integer here, but this should get you started. Note, I've not tested this code ;)